# Cocoa status bar (UIElement) app settings window

Tags: macos, cocoa, window, statusbar, uielement

I got it all working, but when i click on the settings, the settings window (in nswindowcontroller) opens up on the back of other apps running on my mac. I want it in the front so user can see it when he clicks it.

Thank you all!

Comment: finally know how this site work :) i accepted all the questions that were answered :) thank you ... and if someone can help, it will be appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

seems like i got it working finally! :)

```
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
```

when the user clicks the settings menu item, i execute this code :) am writing this just in case if someone will look for a similar thing.